# Loop through a list of CSV files in Powershell

Tags: powershell

This is a simple question so I hope you can help me.
I have a list of 150 CSV files called file1, file2, file3 etc..
I need to run a Powershell script going through every file
Right now im doing this manually by every CSV with this.

`Import-Csv .\PD\file1.csv | .\script.ps1`

Comment: Use `Get-ChildItem` to get your CSV files then pipe the output to `Import-Csv`

Comment: let me try that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem` to discover the files on disk, then use `ForEach-Object` to process them 1 by 1:

```
Get-ChildItem path\to\directory -File -Filter *.csv |ForEach-Object {
  Import-Csv $_.FullName | .\script.ps1
}
```

The [`FullName` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname) will contain the rooted path to the file, eg. `C:\path\to\PD\file1.csv`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Get-ChildItem to list all files in a directory

Then run a loop iterating through each file <.fullname> gives you path of the current file.

```
$files_list=Get-ChildItem "D:\folder location" -Filter "*.csv"

foreach($file in $files_list.FullName)
{
  Import-Csv $file | .\script.ps1
}
```